# Starting a jQuery timer after an event rather than page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a jquery timer from following page:

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#controls

The code is as follows:

```
//Timer
var hms = '00:45:00';   // Time Input
var a = hms.split(':'); 
// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
//console.log(seconds);
var remainSeconds = new Date().getTime() + (seconds*1000);
$('#spanTimer').countdown(remainSeconds)
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (event.elapsed) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('After end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        } else {
            $this.html(event.strftime('Time Remaining: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
        }
    })
//finish.countdown callback, to hide the countdown and other actions
    .on('finish.countdown', function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $("#test").show();
    });
```

The timer is loaded on a div as follows:

```
<div id="spanTimer"></div>
```

The visibility of the div is hidden on page load using css:

```
#spanTimer{
display:none;
}
```

The visibility is toggled based on an event as follows:

```
$('#spanTimer').show();
```

**The issue is that the timer starts running from pageload rather than based on event.** I want to start the timer when #spantimer div is displayed. How is that possible??

In the plugin page i saw an option of Deferred initialization. But since i am a javascript newbie i am unable to understand its usage and how to implement it.

Requesting help from Javascript experts. Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: you can try with if statment like if($("#spantimer ").is(":visible")){ execute code }

Comment: @Ivan and when would that code run?

Answer (score 0):

We can't see whatever it is that triggers your `spanTimer` to be displayed - I mean what event or action triggers the `.show()`.  But whatever it is, you can fire up your countdown at the same time, like this:

```
$('#spanTimer').show().countdown(remainSeconds).on ...
```

Comment: @pamela Does this help?

Comment: sorry, no. As i informed in my post it starts on pageload rather than an event.

Comment: That would mean that your `$('#spanTimer').show()` happens on page load also ...? How is your `.show()` triggered?

Comment: @Pamela the code I show will initialise your countdown at the same time that the `.show()` is called.  If it isn't, something funny is going on - show us the code :-)